# Framework7 stacked modals not working correctly

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

In framework7 I am opening a modal with

> myApp.modal(...)

From within this modal I want to show an alert to the user and I do so with

> myApp.alert(...)

I have

> modalStack: false

so the alert is shown over the modal, the problem is that when the alert is closed, the modal-overlay of the whole app is closed as well (while the first modal is still visible).
I think this is a framework7 bug but maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What's happen if you pass `modalStack` to `true` ?

Comment: @Djiggy: as it should, the alert is queued and only shown AFTER the modal has been closed (clearly not what is intended since I want to use the alert to tell the user to complete all the fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a bug in framework7. I have developed a Pull Request to solve it. I tested it and works fine on my samples but haven't tried it thoroughly with all the options of framework7 modals (so use at your discretion).

Since it overlaps as many overlays as stacked modals, the overlay color gets darker the more there are. When you start to close them, it gets lighter.

[Here are the changes needed to the file modal.js in the source](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/pull/1663/commits/83f97439f427e521e88890249bfe3cd08f0ca624). The same changes can be applied directly (though manually) in framework7.js.